# RethinkDb equivalent for filter between dates

Tags: mysql, rethinkdb

I am really new to ReThinkDB coming from MySQL and I have some tasks that uses ReThinkDB.

Now, I would like to implement something like...

**MySQL:**

```
select * 
from reservations
where 
    room_id = '7cc8e51d-e3fa-4d84-b7e6-9ebf8975754a' and
    ((reservation_start between `11-01-2018 00:00:00` and `11-30-2018 23:59:59`) OR
    (reservation_end between `11-01-2018 00:00:00` and `11-30-2018 23:59:59`))
```

**ReThinkDB:**

This is the equivalent query using `filter()`, thanks to @Peter:

```
r.db("myDb").table("reservations").filter(function(doc){ 
    return 
        doc("room_id").eq("7cc8e51d-e3fa-4d84-b7e6-9ebf8975754a")
            .and(doc("reservation_start").gt("2018-12-01T00:00:00").and(doc("reservation_start").lt("2018-12-10T23:59:59"))
                .or(doc("reservation_end").gt("2018-12-01T00:00:00").and(doc("reservation_end").lt("2018-12-10T23:59:59"))))
    }
)
```

*But I am not sure how to convert the two date range checks into multiple between.*

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what format you store your dates:

Option 1:

```
r.db("myDB").table("reservations").filter(function (doc) {
    return doc("reservation_date").during(
        r.time(2018, 11, 10, 'Z'), r.time(2018, 11, 20, 'Z'));
})
```

option 2:

```
 r.db("myDB").table("reservations").filter(function(doc){ 
  return doc("reservation_date").gt("2018-11-10T18:15:31.000000Z")
    .and(doc("reservation_date").lt("2018-11-20T18:15:31.000000Z"))})
```

Alternative way for more performance:

create index on reservation date:

```
  r.db("myDB").table("reservations").indexCreate("reservation_date")
```

then use the following query:

```
  r.db("myDB").table('reservations')
    .between("2018-11-10T18:15:31.000000Z",
             "2018-11-20T18:15:31.000000Z", {index: "reservation_date"})
```

Comment: Thanks @Peter, I updated the query and now it uses 2 date range checks. I tried using `between()` and it works... but as for the requirement... it needs two checks... `start` and `end`.

Comment: btw, I am evading those with `function(doc){}` since I am not sure how to convert it into java expression.

Comment: Thanks @Peter, I got it working now using filter(), your answer works :)

Answer (score 0):

Now I understand your problem a little better

First to convert your query to java:

```
r.db("myDb").table("reservations").filter(doc ->
    doc.g("room_id").eq("7cc8e51d-e3fa-4d84-b7e6-9ebf8975754a")
      .and(doc.g("reservation_start").gt("2018-12-01T00:00:00").and(doc.g("reservation_start").lt("2018-12-10T23:59:59"))
      .or(doc.g("reservation_end").gt("2018-12-01T00:00:00").and(doc.g("reservation_end").lt("2018-12-10T23:59:59")))))
```

Now optimally You may want to use the room_id as a secondary index:

r.db("myDB").table("reservations").indexCreate("room_id")

And then you can use in your query as:

```
 r.db("myDb").table("reservations")
    .getAll("7cc8e51d-e3fa-4d84-b7e6-9ebf8975754a")
    .optArg("index","room_id")
    .filter(...)
```

> "But I am not sure how to convert the two date range checks into
>   multiple between."

1.) Create a compound array index

```
r.db("myDb").table("reservations").indexCreate(
    "reservation_date", [r.row("reservation_start"), r.row("reservation_end")]
```

2.) use the between query

```
r.db("myDb").table("reservations").between(
    ["2018-12-01T00:00:00", "2018-12-01T00:00:00"], ["2018-12-10T23:59:59", "2018-12-10T23:59:59"], {index: "reservation_date"}
)
```

// note: now this gets tricky when you need the room id as well :)